# (Solved)xacro: Traditional processing is deprecated?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everyone.

I am trying to display a model in gazebo and
I get the following warning:

[image: image description]

xacro: Traditional processing is deprecated. Switch to --inorder processing!
To check for compatibility of your document, use option --check-order.
For more infos, see http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Processing_Order
xacro.py is deprecated; please use xacro instead

How can i solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16124/(solved)xacro:-traditional-processing-is-deprecated?/) by [Daniel Tobon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3221/daniel-tobon/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-05-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) on 2017-05-10**:
This sounds like an XY problem. Is there a larger problem you're trying to solve? The xacro warning is just a warning. It means the robot description is written using xacro, and the roslaunch for it is not passing the --inorder flag. If you have written the robot description and the launch file then follow the link in your answer for instructions on making the warning go away. Otherwise it can be safely ignored.

**Comment by [Daniel Tobon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3221/daniel-tobon/) on 2017-05-11**:
How do I get the launch file to pass the --inorder flag? Should I add a line of code to the launch file to run inorder?

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) on 2017-05-11**:
Use the args attribute on the node tag http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

the solution is in the launch file:

< param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(arg model)" />

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Tobon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3221/daniel-tobon/) with karma: 23 on 2017-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2